# List methods or procedures (with arguments) in compiled Progress 4gl class

Tags: progress-4gl

Is possible get a procedure list (with arguments) in a compiled Progress 4gl class?

Any tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection is supported in 11.6+